# Get value (or other attribute) of lightning:button on click

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Does anyone have an idea of how to get the "value" attribute (or name or anything else) of the lightning:button that triggers an action ?

I tried to grab the button element from the event.currentTarget but it does not have any information.

You can see in this example that I'm trying to figure out which filter corresponds to the button:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.selectedFilters}" var="filter" indexVar="filterIndex">
   <li class="slds-pill slds-m-right--xxx-small" >
     <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-pill__label" title="Full pill label verbiage mirrored here">{!filter.displayValue}</a>
     <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="close" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.resetFilter}" value="{!filterIndex}"/>
  </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

controller:

```
resetFilter : function(component,event,helper) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I could think of is to create my own component that I iterate on and register an onclick event.

Child component :

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="label" type="string"/>
  <aura:attribute name="value" type="object"/>
  <aura:registerEvent name="onclick" type="c:evtDOMEvent"/>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-pill__label" title="Full pill label verbiage mirrored here">{!v.label}</a>
  <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="close" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.triggerOnClickEvent}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Child controller :

```
({
   triggerOnClickEvent : function(component, event, helper) {
     component.getEvent("onclick").fire();
   }
})
```

Parent Component :

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.selectedFilters}" var="filter" indexVar="filterIndex">       
    <li class="slds-pill slds-m-right--xxx-small" >
       <c:uiPill label="{!filter.displayValue}" onclick="{!c.resetFilter}" value="{!filterIndex}"/>
   </li>
 </aura:iteration>
```

Parent Controller

```
resetFilter : function(component,event,helper) {
    console.log(event.getSource().get("v.value"));
},
```

> Now event.getSource().get("v.value") return the proper value

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way I have found today (Going into 2018) is simply by referencing an attribute from your button and fetch it using event.getSource():

```
<lightning:button class="action-btns" value="yourValue" variant="neutral" label="something" onclick="{! c.handleAction }">
```

and from your controller, leverage event.getSource(theAttributeYouNeed) as follows:

```
 handleAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var btnValue = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    }
```

the documentation reference can be found at [Which Button Was Pressed?](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm)

If your button component is nested in another one, @Lucas Ennouchi's approach remains valid.

Answer (score 2):

The open bug for the team that owns the lightning: namespace is ***W-3453049*** if you want to reference this in any communications with Salesforce. To be clear this is an issue in the specific components design that is being addressed and is not a Locker bug.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Release Notes, this will be fixed in Spring '17. You can find more information [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_lightning_base_events.htm). 
The way to go is to use `event.getSource()`:

**Component:**

```
<lightning:button aura:id="button" variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{! c.getMyId }"/>
```

**JS Controller:**

```
getMyId : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(event.getSource().getLocalId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick: `console.log(event.currentTarget.value);`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with additional information?

Comment: Nope.. currentTarget does not have any attribute. event.currentTarget.value is undefined. I'm pretty sure it is due to locker service or component access check that prevent me to get access to the DOM.

Comment: @LucasEnnouchi : The ideal way to get the attributes in lightning is use getAttribute method as follows .. var elem = event.currentTarget;
console.log(elem.getAttribute('name')) .. this approach will work only when locker service critical update is turned off. However this will be fixed in the near future to work with locker services.

Comment: Thank you @Sumuga.  However I won't disable Locker Service. I don't want to start developing without this security because of all the trouble it could cause when I will turn it back on. (already had a bad experience with a client...)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to build your own button component, using an Aura.action attribute (no need to create a new event)  :)

Generic component Button:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="press" type="Aura.Action" access="global" description="JS controller action to perform when button pressed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" access="global" description="Button value"/> 

    <button onclick="{!v.press}" value="{!v.value}">
       <!-- manage your styles here with some input parameters -->
    </button>

</aura:component>
```

Then u can call it like that from any component:

```
<c:Button value="yourvaluehere" press="{!c.onPushTheButton}" />
```

Js to get the value from any component controller :

```
onPushTheButton : function(component, event, helper) {
    var Val = event.target.value;
    // You'll get 'yourvaluehere' in Val, do whatever u need with it :)
}
```

You could also create a Facet component

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="press" type="Aura.Action" access="global" description="JS controller action to perform when button pressed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" access="global" description="Button value"/> 

    <span onclick="{!v.press}" value="{!v.value}">
       {!v.body}
    </span>

</aura:component>
```

that you would call like

```
<c:Button value="yourvaluehere" press="{!c.onPushTheButton}">
     <p style="background-color:green;">MyButton,images,whatever u want</p>
</c:Button>
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas I like your proposition with Aura.Action. I didn't know this feature existed !

Comment: The thing is I cannot get any value from the source component. event.getSource() is not possible. However firing an event (which can be as generic as you want and used by any component) allows you to retrieve attributes.

Comment: Aura.Action is not documented but I really hope they won't decide one day to remove it ;) Depending of your needs you can use your solution or mine, but for my cases it's enough to just know that the button has been pressed and that it has a given value behind :)