# Read value attribute in lightning button in the client js controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, button, attribute

I create a bunch of buttons in a table with aura:iteration. Think of it as one per contact per row to act on the record. Here is the button markup inside a td -

`<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Charge" value="{!s.Id}" onclick="{!c.callMyCallback}" />`

Now, how do I access the value attribute for the button in my client js controller callback? event.currentTarget.value is undefined and event.target.value doesn't work either. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to build your own button component, using an Aura.action attribute :)

Generic component Button:

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="press" type="Aura.Action" access="global" description="JS controller action to perform when button pressed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" access="global" description="Button value"/> 

    <button onclick="{!v.press}" value="{!v.value}">
       <!-- manage your styles here with some input parameters -->
    </button>

</aura:component>
```

Then u can call it like that from any component:

```
<c:Button value="yourvaluehere" press="{!c.onPushTheButton}" />
```

Js to get the value from any component controller :

```
onPushTheButton : function(component, event, helper) {
    var Val = event.target.value;
    // You'll get 'yourvaluehere' in Val, do whatever u need with it :)
}
```

You could also create a Facet component

```
<aura:component>

    <aura:attribute name="press" type="Aura.Action" access="global" description="JS controller action to perform when button pressed"/>
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" access="global" description="Button value"/> 

    <span onclick="{!v.press}" value="{!v.value}">
       {!v.body}
    </span>

</aura:component>
```

that you would call like

```
<c:Button value="yourvaluehere" press="{!c.onPushTheButton}">
     <p style="background-color:green;">MyButton,images,whatever u want</p>
</c:Button>
```

Comment: It is now much simpler to just use 'event.getSource().get("v.value")' as described in Manuel's answer

Answer (score 6):

Now you can use `event.getSource().get("v.value")` function to get lightning button value when clicked.

From the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm):

> In the client-side controller, you can use one of the following methods to find out which button was clicked:
>
> - `event.getSource().getLocalId()` returns the `aura:id` of the clicked button.
> - `event.getSource().get("v.name")` returns the `name` of the clicked button.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get to the attributes with the LockerService. Your best bet is to use the ui:button component so that your callback receives the 'press' event. Then your controller can get the value like this:

```
callMyCallback : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var value = event.getSource().get('v.value');
}
```

Right now, I only use the lightning:button component when I have a single button with a single callback.

Comment: Oh, this is a duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/146057/get-value-or-other-attribute-of-lightningbutton-on-click

Comment: It's now much simpler to use 'event.getSource().get("v.value")' as described in Manuel's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```html
<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Charge" **data-value**="{!s.Id}" onclick="{!c.callMyCallback}" />
```

```javascript
callMyCallback : function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var value = **event.target.dataset.value**;
}
```