# Locker-Service safe passing of data from <a> and <lightning:xyz> to controller

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, locker-service

In my lightning component I loop over records and display links to them:

**1) Works, but is discouraged as it doesn't work in all places**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <a href="{!'/' + stage.id}" />
</aura:iteration
```

**2) Tried that but fails with:**

> Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <a onlick="sforce.one.navigateToSObject({!'/' + stage.id})" />
</aura:iteration
```

**3) How to pass the recordId into myOwnNavigateToSObject()?**

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <a onlick="{!c.myOwnNavigateToSObject}" />
</aura:iteration
```

**My preferred solution is to make 2) work as I see no use of an additional controller function that just delegates work to `navigateToSObject()`.**

Comment: Option 1 should work "everywhere". Do you have a link to any documentation that suggests otherwise?

Comment: @sfdcfox: See the Trailhead https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_navigation where they say: "Don’t use static URLs to Salesforce resources. That is, if you’re adding a link to edit a Contact record, don’t create the link by building a string with a static pattern like link = '/' + accountId + '/e'. In some contexts this works, but in others it doesn’t. Instead, try one of these approaches:"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to all the other "answers" I finally solved it myself. To make it work with:

- **Summer '17 activated Locker-Service**
- **regular `<a>` links AND `<lightning:button>` base components**

I use `id=` for `<a>` and `value=` for `<lightning:button>`:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <a id="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.navigateToSObject}" />
    <lightning:button value="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.navigateToSObject}" />
</aura:iteration>
```

The controller need to check if `getSource` is defined and use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target` in case it is not.

```
navigateToSObject: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    var recordId = (event.getSource != undefined) ? event.getSource().get("v.value") 
                                                  : event.currentTarget.id;
    var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    evt.setParams({
        "recordId": recordId,
        "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
    evt.fire(); 
}
```

Comment: Just a thought you can kind of have different methods on a tag and button and from there call a common method which will fire the event. This will give you better control  incase you want to add more logic between an a tag and button

Comment: Sure thing! If I build a generic lib to solve this i would definitly have to work on making this more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
<a id="{!record.Id}" onclick="{!c.myOwnNavigateToSObject}" />
</aura:iteration
```

an then in the controller:

```
myOwnNavigateToSObject: function(component, event, helper){
    var idx = event.target.id;        
    var sObectEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    sObectEvent .setParams({
    "recordId": idx  ,
    "slideDevName": "detail"
    });
    sObectEvent.fire(); 
},
```

Comment: Really verbose compared to Visualforce, but ok. How would that work I I have <lightning:button> instead of <a> tags. They are not allowed to add an id attribute?

Comment: You could use the "value" attribute

Comment: No, sorry, I have tested it and you can't do that with a lightning:button. You can see some solutions here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147166/read-value-attribute-in-lightning-button-in-the-client-js-controller/147185

Comment: Even "event.target.id" evaluates to null. :-(

Comment: If you're binding events to the component (e.g. lightning:button) instead of an HTML element, you can get the event source via `event.getSource()`.You can't add an "id" attribute to it, but you can add a local "aura:id", which can later be retrieved via `event.getSource().getLocalId()`. More info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_which_button_pressed.htm).

Answer (score 1):

2) won't work not only due to mixing expressions and literals but primarily because any arbitrary Javascript placed in the component markup is ignored by the framework. As described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/js_client_side_controller.htm):

> Any browser DOM element event starting with on, such as onclick or onkeypress, can be wired to a controller action. You can only wire browser events to controller actions.

You can pass the id somewhere in the link markup (id or data-* attributes) as described by Acabo.

A more "component-oriented" approach would be to create a separate component for the item and in that component's controller invoke `navigateToSObject` in the context of that single record. Something along the lines of:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="record">
    <c:item record="{!record}"/>
</aura:iteration
```

And in the `item` component:

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="SObject" />

<a onlick="{!c.navigate}" />
```

Now your custom `navigate` method operates in the context of a single record.

Comment: Creating an extra component just to call an URL seems so much to much that this is not a solution at all. Sorry.

Comment: You may not like it, but that's the proper "Lightning" way about it :). And while it may be indeed too much for a simple button, it structures your app into nice encapsulated components.